# Auto populate "Form::text" from "Form::model" after adding extra attribute(class) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I am currently rendering and populating a form in laravel [using the laravelcollective plugin](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html). this is working as expected:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['action' => 'user@updateUser']) !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('user_name', 'Name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('user_name') !!}
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The above code generates the form and populates the input field with the user's name.

If I want to add a class attribute to the form input like so:

```
{!! Form::text('user_name', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

It does not populate the input value because in theory I've set the default value (second parameter) to `''`.

Is there a way of populating the value and adding a class without explicitly doing so like this:

```
{!! Form::text('user_name', $user->user_name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

By doing the above it defeats the object of rendering the form via a model `{!! Form::model($user, ['action' => 'user@updateUser']) !!}` as I may as well parse the `$user` as a variable onto the template, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can use `null` instead `""` blank

```
{!! Form::text('user_name', null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

You can also use [`old`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input) function

```
{!! Form::text('user_name', $user->user_name or old('user_name'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

This `$user->user_name or old('user_name')` can be expressed as

If `$user->user_name` is exist then put value of `$user->user_name` otherwise check for `old input` which is `""` blank first time and have some value if you redirect back if any error comes.

or simply use `isset` method or in php 7 use `$user->user_name ?? ''`

```
{!! Form::text('user_name', $user->user_name ?? '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Also can be written as `old('user_name', $user->user_name)`.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh : No it will not work as you suggest, second param of `old` is for default value and if first time you come there will be no value and you will get error.

Comment: Can write as: `old('user_name', empty($user->user_name) ? '' : $user->user_name)`

Comment: Yes now it will work :), another alternative is `old('user_name', $user->user_name ?? '')`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't resolve the issue as I still need to explicitly call `$user->user_name` as opposed to letting the `Form::` method populate it.

Comment: @steve that's not strictly true, this answer is giving you full options. You could keep it simple, without calling the variable like so `{!! Form::text('user_name', old('user_name'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}` this would also aid in form validation too.

Comment: @steve : use `null` as `{!! Form::text('user_name', null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

Comment: @C2486 `null` works, thanks. Could you put that as the main answer and i'll mark it as correct.